# How to load a new document on Chrome's extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome, popup

I need to load different documents in a popup. I'm using this:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"newpage.html"});
```

It works, except that the new page is not displayed until I click the extension button again. Opera has a similar API, but the popup content is actually replaced even if the popup is already opened.

So, how do I make Chrome popup load the new page without clicking the extension button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an iframe or div and populate it with the content you want. Example:

```
<!-- popup.html -->
<!-- This doesn't change -->
<html>
<body>
     <!-- But the content of this container does -->
     <div id="content" style="display:none"></id>

     <!-- By using a script like this: -->
     <script>
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML
                 = "<iframe src=\"newpage.html\" />";
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I won't be able to communicate with the background page from an iframe, right? I still need to send messages from each loaded page to the extension background.

Comment: In that case, you can use XmlHttpRequest to do it, but then you need permissions.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to solve the problem with divs, moving some stuff to notifications, setting the options page to be opened on a new tab and sending messages back and forth between the background process and the popup.